# Downloading file from file.io "X-Cache: LambdaExecutionError from cloudfront" "Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Tags: c#, download, upload, httprequest

I'm trying to set up a simple upload download for small files via file.io.

According to their API, the following should work as a test:

```
        public static void TestUploadDownload()
    {
        byte[] resStr = client.UploadFile("https://file.io", @"C:\Games\test.txt");
        string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resStr);
        UploadResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadResponse>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resStr));
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), response.link))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "*/*");
                Console.WriteLine(request.ToString());
                Task<HttpResponseMessage> res = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                res.Wait();
                HttpResponseMessage r = res.Result;
                Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class UploadResponse
    {
        public string success { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public bool @private { get; set; }
        public int downloads { get; set; }
        public int maxDownloads { get; set; }
        public bool autoDelete { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string mimeType { get; set; }
        public string created { get; set; }
        public string modified { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

The request printout looks like this:

```
Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://file.io/L8Qp3xJ4vqVo', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  accept: */*
}
```

I know it's uploaded successfully because I get the following output:

And when I go to the link it confirms the file was uploaded.

```
{"success":true,"status":200,"id":"15a117d0-ea34-11eb-9a70-5b2a19fad8fa","key":"LLUEQ8tYvd56","name":"test.txt","link":"https://file.io/LLUEQ8tYvd56","private":false,"expires":"2021-08-04T14:58:18.701Z","downloads":0,"maxDownloads":1,"autoDelete":true,"size":15,"mimeType":"application/octet-stream","created":"2021-07-21T14:58:18.701Z","modified":"2021-07-21T14:58:18.701Z"}
```

However, the HttpResponseMessage always returns:

```
StatusCode: 503, ReasonPhrase: 'Service Temporarily Unavailable', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Cache: LambdaExecutionError from cloudfront
  X-Amz-Cf-Pop: AMS1-C1
  X-Amz-Cf-Id: A4jZfWzl_mMPXM0xNA1rfCki2dP6BisRvAjO-6rAoJ4iO0D4vMXUSA==
  Date: Wed, 21 Jul 2021 14:58:20 GMT
  Server: CloudFront
  Via: 1.1 4ce5e5162c2d4fc9022ceb290f794ffe.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
  Content-Length: 1019
  Content-Type: text/html
}
```

Is the service actually temporarily unavailable or am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT:
Reading the body of the HttpResponseMessage we get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>503 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 13FAiVlp7dwuOBEdaabvAtZEJhBz3h8HMfowEnVGtberx9WxCB0Czg==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: what is this: 'X-Cache: LambdaExecutionError from cloudfront'?

Comment: Some kind of service they use that processes trafic? I'm not very versed in API calls.